# Why slideshow wont work on server but work offline

Tags: javascript, html, css

My problem is that when i open index.html in browser(offline) image slider works great. But when i try to open it on server (it takes actually long time to load images are over 5mb) it wont slide. You can try to click on that white dots in right corner and nothing happen. Thanks for any advice.

Code is

```
<!-- BEGIN - SlideShow -->
<div class="ImageSlider">
    <div class="ImageSlider-scroller">
        <ul class="ImageSlider-items">
            <li class="ImageSlider-item" style="background-image: url(http://vitas.sk/OnlineTv/images/1.jpg);"></li>
            <li class="ImageSlider-item" style="background-image: url(http://vitas.sk/OnlineTv/images/2.jpg);"></li>
            <li class="ImageSlider-item" style="background-image: url(http://vitas.sk/OnlineTv/images/3.jpg);"></li>
        </ul>
            <nav class="ImageSlider-indicators">
                <a href="javascript: void 0;" class="ImageSlider-indicator js-ImageSlider-dot"></a>
                <a href="javascript: void 0;" class="ImageSlider-indicator js-ImageSlider-dot"></a>
                <a href="javascript: void 0;" class="ImageSlider-indicator js-ImageSlider-dot"></a>
            </nav>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- END - SlideShow -->

/* Image Slider */
.ImageSlider {
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
  height: 50%;
}

.ImageSlider-button {
  width: 40px;
  border: none;
  background: transparent;
  color: #000000;
  font-size: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  outline: none;
  opacity: 0.5;
  transition: opacity 300ms ease-out;
}

.ImageSlider-button:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.ImageSlider-scroller {
  flex: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.ImageSlider-items {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-size: 0;
  line-height: 0;
  transition: transform 0.6s cubic-bezier(1, 0, 0, 1);
}

.ImageSlider-item {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-bottom: 31.25%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
}

.ImageSlider-indicators {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  display: block;
  text-align: right;
  padding: 40px 140px;
  font-size: 0;
}

.ImageSlider-indicator {
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: 2px solid #FFFFFF;
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
  border-radius: 16px;
  margin: 0 4px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  transition: background-color 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

.ImageSlider-indicator:hover,
.ImageSlider-indicator--is-active {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

And Js

```
/* global Modernizr */

if (!Object.assign) {
  Object.defineProperty(Object, 'assign', {
    enumerable: false,
    configurable: true,
    writable: true,
    value: function(target) {
      'use strict';
      if (target === undefined || target === null) {
        throw new TypeError('Cannot convert first argument to object');
      }

      var to = Object(target);
      for (var i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        var nextSource = arguments[i];
        if (nextSource === undefined || nextSource === null) {
          continue;
        }
        nextSource = Object(nextSource);

        var keysArray = Object.keys(nextSource);
        for (var nextIndex = 0, len = keysArray.length; nextIndex < len; nextIndex++) {
          var nextKey = keysArray[nextIndex];
          var desc = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(nextSource, nextKey);
          if (desc !== undefined && desc.enumerable) {
            to[nextKey] = nextSource[nextKey];
          }
        }
      }
      return to;
    }
  });
}

(function(window, document, Modernizr) {
  "use strict";

  var d = document;
  var transform = Modernizr.prefixed('transform');

  function ImageSliderIndicators(imageSlider, options) {
    this.imageSlider = imageSlider;
    this.options = Object.assign({}, ImageSliderIndicators.DEFAULTS, options || {});
    this.el = d.querySelector('.' + this.options.indicatorsClass);
    this.indicators = [].slice.call(d.querySelectorAll('.' + this.options.indicatorClass));

    this.imageSlider.el.addEventListener('positionChanged', this.onPositionChanged.bind(this));
    this.el.addEventListener('click', this.onIndicatorClick.bind(this), false);
    this.onPositionChanged();
  }

  ImageSliderIndicators.DEFAULTS = {
    indicatorsClass: 'ImageSlider-indicators',
    indicatorClass: 'ImageSlider-indicator',
    indicatorActiveClass: 'ImageSlider-indicator--is-active'
  };

  ImageSliderIndicators.prototype.onIndicatorClick = function onIndicatorClick(event) {
    var position = this.indicators.indexOf(event.target);
    if (position !== -1) {
      this.imageSlider.goto(position);
    }
  };

  ImageSliderIndicators.prototype.onPositionChanged = function onPositionChanged() {
    var self = this;
    this.indicators.forEach(function(element, index) {
      var action = index === self.imageSlider.position ? 'add' : 'remove';
      element.classList[action](self.options.indicatorActiveClass);
    });
  };

  function ImageSlider(options) {
    this.options = Object.assign({}, ImageSlider.DEFAULTS, options || {});
    this.position = 0;
    this.el = d.querySelector('.' + this.options.imageSliderClass);
    this.items = d.querySelector('.' + this.options.itemsClass);
    this.itemCount = d.querySelectorAll('.' + this.options.itemClass).length;
    this.scroller = d.querySelector('.' + this.options.scrollerClass);
    this.previousButton = d.querySelector('.' + this.options.previousButtonClass);
    this.nextButton = d.querySelector('.' + this.options.nextButtonClass);
    this.indicators = new ImageSliderIndicators(this, this.options.indicators);

    window.addEventListener('resize', this.render.bind(this));
    this.nextButton && this.nextButton.addEventListener('click', this.next.bind(this));
    this.previousButton && this.previousButton.addEventListener('click', this.previous.bind(this));
  }

  ImageSlider.DEFAULTS = {
    imageSliderClass: 'ImageSlider',
    itemsClass: 'ImageSlider-items',
    itemClass: 'ImageSlider-item',
    scrollerClass: 'ImageSlider-scroller',
    previousButtonClass: 'js-ImageSlider-button--previous',
    nextButtonClass: 'js-ImageSlider-button--next'
  };

  ImageSlider.prototype.render = function render() {
    this.items.style[transform] = 'translate3d(' + (-this.position * this.items.offsetWidth) + 'px,0,0)';
  };

  ImageSlider.prototype.goto = function goto(position) {
    var event = d.createEvent('Event');
    event.initEvent('positionChanged', true, true);
    this.position = position;
    this.el.dispatchEvent(event);
    this.render();
  };

  ImageSlider.prototype.previous = function previous() {
    this.goto((this.position + (this.itemCount - 1)) % this.itemCount);
  };

  ImageSlider.prototype.next = function next() {
    this.goto((this.position + 1) % this.itemCount);
  };

  window.ImageSlider = ImageSlider;

}).call(this, window, window.document, Modernizr);

new ImageSlider();
```

Comment: Did you look for some script errors? Use the F12 tools provided by the browser you use.

Comment: Have you looked at the console in devtools? I’m on an iPad, so I can’t right now, but one thing I notice is that your site is HTTPS  but your slider images have full URLs with an HTTP protocol. May not be a big deal, but you should match the protocol or, better, use relative URLs.

Comment: in package.json you need to include dependency before deploying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an JavaScript error in your code before the slider initialization.

`Uncaught ReferenceError: Modernizr is not defined`

You should fix this dependency issue and I guess your slider will work.

(maybe change http to https in Modernizr url)

Answer (score 0):

For me my browser are blocking Modernizr  script and a bunch of other thing to be loaded